# calculating the occurrences of word lengths in a file with ruby

Tags: ruby

I am currently trying to count the occurrences of word lengths in a file. The method looks like this:

```
def count_words_of_each_length_in_a_file(file_path)
  hash = {}
  File.open(file_path,"r") do |f|
    f.each_line do |line|
      line.split(" ").each do |word|
        hash.key?(word.length) ? hash[word.length] += 1 : hash[word.length] = 1
      end
    end
  end
  hash
end
```

It is not returning the expected values, can anyone tell me why or point me towards a better solution?

Comment: Have you written a test with a small file to check if the method works?

Comment: If it doesn't return the expected values, what does it return instead? Are the numbers not correct or does it raise an error?

Comment: Yes I have a test wriiten and it passes on one file but not another. I think the problem is its not calculating the correct length of a word when it has a punctuation mark after it.

Comment: Just saying "it is not returning the expected values" is a terrible problem description.

Comment: Try `line.delete("\s.!?:;").split.each do |word|` or `line.split(/[\s.!?:;]/).each do |word|`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `String#scan` passing in the regex for any word or `'` character:

```
scan(/[\w\']+/)
```

So your code looks like this:

```
#script.rb

def count_words_of_each_length_in_a_file(file_path)
  hash = {}
  File.open(file_path,"r") do |f|
    f.each_line do |line|
      line.scan(/[\w\']+/).each do |word|
        hash.key?(word.length) ? hash[word.length] += 1 : hash[word.length] = 1
      end
    end
  end
  hash
end
```

#### Example

```
#test.rb
o
tw tw
thr thr, thr thr
four four. four four
they've they've
```

Then run your program:

```
count_words_of_each_length_in_a_file('./test.rb')
#=> {1=>1, 2=>2, 3=>4, 4=>4, 7=>2}
```

*caveat: the above solution is a starting point but not altogether watertight. For example consider, hyphenated-words. What are your rules for dealing with these types of words?*

Comment: If you change `h={}` to `h=Hash.new(0)`, you can replace your most-indented line with `hash[word.length] += 1`. Taking it a step farther, if you also replace `f.each_line do |line|` with `f.each_line.with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |line, hash|`, you can remove the penultimate line (`hash`) as well as `hash={}`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I kinda went with a quick answer and couldn't see an immediate refactoring, so this is nice thanks. I always overlook using `each_with_object`/`with_object` methods, something that will improve with experience I hope.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that the only thing wrong with your code is that you don't first remove punctuation. We might wish to remove the following characters:

```
BAD_CHARS = '.?!,:;"-/'
```

Add other characters as appropriate. The apostrophe/single quote character is problematic. You may want to keep it for contractions ("don't"), but remove it for possessives (e.g., "Rufus'" or "Sue's", the latter producing the word "Sues", yet another problem) and quoted strings ("She said, 'Get lost!'"). Differentiating between the cases is of course difficult. For the purpose of the answer I will not delete apostrophes/single quotes.

I suggest you write the method as follows.

**Code**

```
def count_words_by_length(file_path)
  IO.foreach(file_path).with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |line, h|
    line.delete(BAD_CHARS).split.each { |word| h[word.length] += 1 } }
end
```

**Example**

```
str = "Let us wish the new President well,\neven if through gritted teeth."    
FName = "test"
IO.write(FName, str)
  #=> 66

count_words_by_length(FName)
  #=> {3=>3, 2=>2, 4=>3, 9=>1, 7=>2, 5=>1}
```

**Explanation**

Perhaps the best way to explain what is going on here is insert some `puts` statements and re-run the code.

```
def count_words_by_length(file_path)
  enum0 = IO.foreach(file_path)
  puts "enum0=#{enum0}"
  enum1 = enum0.with_object(Hash.new(0))
  puts "enum1=#{enum1}"
  puts "enum1.to_a=#{enum1.to_a}" # Show elements to be generated by enumerator
  enum1.each do |line, h|
    puts "line=#{line}"
    puts "  h=#{h}"
    str = line.delete(BAD_CHARS)
    puts "  str=#{str}"
    arr = str.split
    puts "  arr=#{arr}"
    arr.each do |word|
      h[word.length] += 1
      puts "    word=#{word.ljust(9)} length=#{word.length} h=#{h}" 
    end
  end  
end
count_words_by_length(FName)
```

Then

```
count_words_by_length(FName)
```

prints the following.

```
enum0=#<Enumerator:0x007ff782138130>
enum1=#<Enumerator:0x007ff782138018>
enum1.to_a=[["Let us wish the new President well,\n", {}],
            ["even if through gritted teeth.", {}]]
line=Let us wish the new President well,
  h={}
  str=Let us wish the new President well
  arr=["Let", "us", "wish", "the", "new", "President", "well"]
    word=Let       length=3 h={3=>1}
    word=us        length=2 h={3=>1, 2=>1}
    word=wish      length=4 h={3=>1, 2=>1, 4=>1}
    word=the       length=3 h={3=>2, 2=>1, 4=>1}
    word=new       length=3 h={3=>3, 2=>1, 4=>1}
    word=President length=9 h={3=>3, 2=>1, 4=>1, 9=>1}
    word=well      length=4 h={3=>3, 2=>1, 4=>2, 9=>1}
line=even if through gritted teeth.
  h={3=>3, 2=>1, 4=>2, 9=>1}
  str=even if through gritted teeth
  arr=["even", "if", "through", "gritted", "teeth"]
    word=even      length=4 h={3=>3, 2=>1, 4=>3, 9=>1}
    word=if        length=2 h={3=>3, 2=>2, 4=>3, 9=>1}
    word=through   length=7 h={3=>3, 2=>2, 4=>3, 9=>1, 7=>1}
    word=gritted   length=7 h={3=>3, 2=>2, 4=>3, 9=>1, 7=>2}
    word=teeth     length=5 h={3=>3, 2=>2, 4=>3, 9=>1, 7=>2, 5=>1}
```

`IO.foreach` and `IO.write` would often be written `File.foreach` and `File.write`. That is permissible because `File` is a subclass of `IO` (`File < IO #=> true`).